# How to customize a PHP url token with a defined variable in a python script?

Tags: php, python, json

I am getting a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` when i want to customise the url token where "id" is needed.

In place of one single result returned by a single id (say 303) i want to have the result for all the ids declared in the variable "station" retrieved from another url. 
the code is as follows:

```js
import urllib2
import json

#assign the url
url="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/swd_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22operacja%22:%22stacje%22}"

# open the url 
json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(str(url))
output= json.load(json_obj) 
station_res= output ['data'] ['features']
for item in station_res:
 station= item['id']
url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:}" +str(station)
 json_obj2= urllib2.urlopen(str(url1))
 output2= json.load(json_obj2)
 for item2 in output2 ['data']:
  print item2
```

I tried to put "stations" as a string in the "url1" but it still doesn't recognise the url and returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    `File "stations.py", line 23, in <module>`
        `for item2 in output2 ['data']:`
```

`KeyError: 'data'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
url1 = 'http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:' + str(station) + '}'
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
station= item ['id']
url1="http://ewodr.wodr.poznan.pl/doradztwo/swd/meteo_api.php?dane={%22token%22:%22pcss%22,%22id%22:}" +str(station)
```

You are trying to join an String with an Integer, what generate this error.

Comment: ¿In wich line it specifies the error? Is the only point where you can have this kind of error...

Comment: It works perfect for me. I have used the code from here, added the str() and it works. You have too a problem with indentation (at least in the copy paste of code here)

Comment: I changed the code little bit according to my requirement and I tried to put "stations" as a string in the "url1" but it still doesn't recognise the url and returns an error:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):`
        `File "stations.py", line 23, in <module>`
            `for item2 in output2 ['data']:`
`KeyError: 'data'`

Comment: @samb It seems that you are having now a different problem, and it must be in other question because you have changed the code. With the code that was written the problem was that, ive run it and it works perfectly.

Comment: But you are getting a JSON with your code that have two keys: error and success. You are trying to get data, and data doesnt exist in the JSON.